# mysql server configuration on windows

Tags: mysql

am installed mysqlserver on windows(xp) another system as server....i want to access mysql from (i.e create table) client machine.client machine does't have mysql..and installed all tools..how can i connect from client..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of Mysql tools, http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Comment: There you can find a client to connect to a remote database.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a pure windows system then use Putty to connect to remote client.
After that navigate to the mysql server directory. 
YOu can then use the above mentioned commands to start,stop mysql server/ add tables etc..